# Arduino analogRead function pin 0 not working

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I would like to know if someone met the same problem on Arduino board. Know if there is a solution ? 
My Arduino board has only 1 month. The pin 0 worked well before. I don't know if it's possible to "burn" a pin. (ex : use a too high voltage ? )
[Output A0 connected to 5V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNkZJ.png) [Output A1 connected to V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaYh3.png)

Comment: A0 or digital pin 0?

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshots you provided it shows the value on the pin, so technically speaking your analogRead has no problems. Check the link and connections. But regarding your question - yes, you can burn pin and even board with high voltage, so don't forget resistance when it's needed.
Also good practice to use arduino macro for analog pins like `analogRead(A0);` which is perfectly fine for arduino

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think i burnt the analogPin 0 because it has worked fine before and now it returns always the same value. I will continue to use others pins. Because i think i can't fix the AnalogPin 0 problem.

Comment: it does happen sometimes. However in my experience if you run the same software but get wrong results the problem most of the time is in hardware setup aka wires not connected or circuit shorting. Pin itself can burn but usually if it burns it's entire board. Change pins to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots show that the values read from A0 are changing (190 first, 300 second). That suggests that the problem lies in the electrical connection. Try to resolder the A0 connector pin, and possibly appropriate pin of the microcontroller. Check if the path leading from the connector to microcontroller pin is not cut somewhere.